# Emulate console by sending data on one UDP port, and receive text from another

Tags: console, udp, sockets, socat

I'm trying to establish a “console-like” connection with a [National Instruments cRIO-FRC.](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-19103)

It broadcasts its console output onto `255.255.255.255`, UDP port `6666`. I can listen to it with:

```
socat UDP-RECV:6666,broadcast,reuseaddr -
```

It listens to commands on its IP address, UDP port  `6668`. I can send commands with:

```
socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:10.8.54.2:6668,broadcast,reuslsddr
```

However, these 2 commands run in separate terminals; i.e. I have to type into one, and view results in another window. Is there a way to concurrently run these two programs? Or is there a more appropriate program to use other than `socat`?

Answer (score 0):

Ampersand?

```
socat UDP-RECV:6666,broadcast,reuseaddr - &
socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:10.8.54.2:6668,broadcast,reuslsddr
```

Comment: I thought so too, but it doesn't work. If I do just `socat UDP-RECV:6666,broadcast,reuseaddr - &`, and call commands from another terminal, the output shows fine. However, the moment I do another comand on that first, e.g. ls, I get "[1]+  Stopped                 socat UDP-RECV:6666,broadcast -"

Comment: Needs a socat patch?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Seems like socat application "reuses" udp port opened in one terminal. So starting new socat instance in the same terminal causes the closing of the first established connection. Thought you need to contact socat's authors and report the issue.